# Return false y mostrar mensaje

Tags: php

De nuevo pidiendo ayuda, les dejo parte del código:

**Controlador**

```
$strProyecto = $conex->getIndCol('id', sqlProyectos());//proyectos válidos.
if ($opcion3 == 'save') { 
    $proyecto_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'proyecto_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);//id del proyecto seleccionado
    if ($proyecto_id > 0) {
        $aProyecto = array("proyecto_id"=>$proyecto_id);//id del proyecto seleccionado convertido en array para que sea parámetro de getTareasPendientes
        $aTarea = array();
        $tareasP = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex, '', $aProyecto);//datos de tareas pendientes del proyecto seleccionado
        foreach ($tareasP as $ids) {
            $tarea_id = $ids['id'];
            $_Tarea = new Tarea($tarea_id, $conex);
            $cancelar = $_Tarea->cancelarTarea($sys_Usuario, $proyecto_id);//método para cancelar tareas pendientes
            if (!$cancelar == true) {//resultado de cancelarTarea, interrumpe el ciclo y muestra el id de la tarea en la que fue interrumpido
                $error = $tarea_id;
//----------AQUÍ ES DONDE QUIERO LLAMAR EL $msg
                break;
            }
            array_push($aTarea, $tarea_id);//guarda el id de la tarea que fue cancelada, repitiendo el ciclo hasta que se interrumpa
        }
        $resultnum = count($aTarea);
        $resultid = json_encode($aTarea);
        if (empty($error)) $error = null;
        showAviso('Resultado', 'Tareas canceladas: '.$resultnum.' <br>
            ID de tareas canceladas: '.$resultid.' <br>
            No se puede cancelar la tarea ID: '.$error.' <br>
            '.$msg.'', true);
    }
```

**Modelo**

```
public function cancelarTarea(Usuario $_Usuario, $proyecto_id) {
    $tarea_id = $this->getId();
    $conex = $_Usuario->getConexBD();
    $idUsuario = $_Usuario->getIdUsuario();
    $_Proyecto = new Proyecto($conex, $proyecto_id);
    $asesor = $_Proyecto->getResponACliente();//array de objetis tipo Usuario
    if(!empty($asesor) && array_key_exists($idUsuario, $asesor)) {
        $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE id = '$tarea_id'");
        regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', 'estatus -- Cancelada', $tarea_id);
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
//VARIABLE $msg QUE QUIERO MANDAR AL CONTROLADOR
        $msg = "Usuario no asesor del proyecto";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Lo que quiero es que dentro del **modelo** haya una variable `$msg` que muestre un mensaje y dentro del **controlador** poder llamar esa variable en donde coloqué el comentario `//----------AQUÍ ES DONDE QUIERO LLAMAR EL $msg` para después utilizarla dentro de `showAviso`.

Espero se entienda y de antemano gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer que cancelarTarea te regrese un map o un arreglo donde el primer index sea el boolean que necesitas para la validación y el segundo index sea el $msg

Comment: `return array($result,$msg)`;

Comment: Si he entendido bien, quieres que `cancelarTarea` te devuelva el texto de `$msg` y también el valor de `$result`. Lo que puedes hacer es meter ambas cosas en un array y luego leerlo en el controlador. Ejemplo: `$arrResult=array("msg"=>$msg, "result"=>$result); return $arrResult;`  y luego lees `$arrResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A.** Habría que modificar el **modelo** de la siguiente manera:

- Crear una variable `$msg=""` al principio la cual tomará el valor del mensaje en caso de que `$result` sea `false`.
- Hacer que `cancelarTarea` devuelva un array, al cual he llamado `$arrResult`. El mismo tendrá dos llaves, una podría llamarse `msg`, la cual contendrá el texto del mensaje, y la otra podría llamarse `result`, la cual contendrá el valor booleano de `$result`

  ```
  public function cancelarTarea(Usuario $_Usuario, $proyecto_id) {
  //Definimos $msg, para no tener un undefined index en caso de que $result sea true
  $msg="";

  $tarea_id = $this->getId();
  $conex = $_Usuario->getConexBD();
  $idUsuario = $_Usuario->getIdUsuario();
  $_Proyecto = new Proyecto($conex, $proyecto_id);
  $asesor = $_Proyecto->getResponACliente();//array de objetis tipo Usuario
  if(!empty($asesor) && array_key_exists($idUsuario, $asesor)) {
      $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE id = '$tarea_id'");
      regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', 'estatus -- Cancelada', $tarea_id);
      $result = true;
  }
  else {
      $result = false;
  // VARIABLE $msg QUE QUIERO MANDAR AL CONTROLADOR
      $msg = "Usuario no asesor del proyecto";
  }
  $arrResult=array("msg"=>$msg, "result"=>$result);
  return $arrResult;
  }
  ```

**B.** Luego, en el **controlador**

En la variable `$cancelar` tendrás el array devuelto. Y podrás obtener y usar el valor de cada clave sencillamente con esto: `$cancelar['result']`  para obtener el valor de la clave `result` y `$cancelar['msg']`  para obtener el texto del mensaje:

```
...


            $cancelar = $_Tarea->cancelarTarea($sys_Usuario, $proyecto_id);//método para cancelar tareas pendientes
            if (!$cancelar['result'] == true) {//resultado de cancelarTarea, interrumpe el ciclo y muestra el id de la tarea en la que fue interrumpido
                $error = $tarea_id;
//----------AQUÍ ES DONDE QUIERO LLAMAR EL $msg
                echo $cancelar['msg'];
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Esa era mi duda, saber cómo mandar el booleano y la variable con el mensaje y de qué forma recibirlo para leerlo, ¡muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto @PalomaAG Los votos a favor en las respuestas que te ayudan a resolver los problemas también son motivadores para quienes respondemos. Saludos.